# How can i get a large number of text boxs to subtract from each other

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a program where a user inputs numbers into a subtraction equation and the program tells them if they are right or wrong and what the correct answer is in a label. There are 20 different equations with 3 text boxes each. The first two text boxes are for the two numbers that are being subtracted and the third text box is the answer. I declared them into a array but I can't figure out how make them subtract. The code i have so far is:

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim txtNumber1() As TextBox = {txt1Number1, txt2Number1, txt3Number1, txt4Number1, txt5Number1, txt6Number1, txt7Number1, txt8Number1, txt9Number1, txt10Number1, txt11Number1, txt12Number1, txt13Number1, txt14Number1, txt15Number1, txt16Number1, txt17Number1, txt18Number1, txt19Number1, txt20Number1}
    Dim txtNumber2() As TextBox = {txt1Number2, txt2Number2, txt3Number2, txt4Number2, txt5Number2, txt6Number2, txt7Number2, txt8Number2, txt9Number2, txt10Number2, txt11Number2, txt12Number2, txt13Number2, txt14Number2, txt15Number2, txt16Number2, txt17Number2, txt18Number2, txt19Number2, txt20Number2}
    Dim txtAnswer() As TextBox = {txt1Answer, txt2Answer, txt3Answer, txt4Answer, txt5Answer, txt6Answer, txt7Answer, txt8Answer, txt9Answer, txt10Answer, txt11Answer, txt12Answer, txt13Answer, txt14Answer, txt15Answer, txt16Answer, txt17Answer, txt18Answer, txt19Answer, txt20Answer}
    Dim intAnswer() As Integer
    For i = 0 To txtNumber1.Length - 1
        intAnswer(i) = txtNumber1(i) - txtNumber2(i)
    Next
```

I also can't figure out how i would make each answer display into a label. I think it would be some like

```
If intAnswer(0) = txtAnswer(0) Then
   Me.lblAnswer1.Text = "Correct:" & intAnswer(0)
Else
   Me.lblAnswer1.Text = "Incorrect:" & intAnswer(0)
End If
```

But I'm not sure how i would loop that to make it do all 20 labels, or would i just need to have it 20 different times, one for each label.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to create a user control with 3 labels and 3 textboxes on each. Then you only need to code this much, and wrap this logic in a loop to repeat as many times as you want. Basically, narrow down your problem to "I only have 1 equation", solve it using this approach, the rest is as easy as using adding a loop to your code.

Comment: I think this answer is a bit to hightec based on the question. I think the simple TextBox.Text fix is enough this time. I do however agree with your answer.